# Failed at the firstApp@0.1.0 eject script react-native-scripts eject

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am following an online tutorial and did the following steps:

> 1. npm install -g create-react-native-app
> 2. create-react-native-app firstApp
> 3. npm run eject

but the eject step gives me an error.

I have tried with multiple node/npm versions, like `8.9.4/5.6.0` (this gives message in the first step itself, saying I should use `npm 4` because `npm 5` is not supported), then I used `7.10.1/4.2.0` and with this version I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "eject"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firstApp@0.1.0 eject: `react-native-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firstApp@0.1.0 eject script 'react-native-scripts eject'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the firstApp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-native-scripts eject
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs firstApp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls firstApp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```